# Copy text from remote via iTerm2 with Tmux to OS X clipboard

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

I'd tried using iTerm2 beta Build 1.0.0.20120724 and using `bind C-y run-shell "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh -c 'tmux show-buffer | pbcopy'"` in .tmux.conf but none works.

The solutions I found aren't specific about the system and conditions. Hence I hope the problem statement here is clear ie. Copying text from **remote** to OS X clipboard via iTerm2 with Tmux.

Problem:

1. Copy text output from cat of a log file that's longer than a screen.
2. Copy text from vertically* split screen (left and right panes) without copying the text from the other pane.
   *not sure if it should be called vertically or horizontally split.
3. Copy text through Vim that's longer than a screen.

I'm aware of holding <kbd>alt</kbd> while clicking and drag to select the text. But the problem arises when you need to scroll, or are working in more than 1 pane.

Comment: When you say "remote", do you mean you are running `tmux` on the remote side of an `ssh` connection?

Comment: @chepner yes, you're right.

Comment: automizu's answer may be exactly what you need, but I'll refer you to [my own answer on unix stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82850/how-can-i-scroll-screen-or-tmux-buffer-without-pausing-the-application/82868#82868). In addition to that, you would probably want tmux's `save-buffer` command.

Answer (score 1):

This app might solve your problem, [clipper](https://wincent.com/products/clipper).

I came across this software sometime earlier, but I have never used it. It has a screencast and it seems just to fit your need exactly.

Answer (score 0):

JIC, in some cases it'd be enough to just run command through SSH and copy result with pbcopy, like this:

```
ssh yourhost.net 'ls /' | pbcopy
```

Comment: Please explain 'in some cases'

Comment: With some cases he probably means where you have a direct connection the the target machine and are able to reverse ssh the pbcopy command. In that scenario this works.